# Map two dimensional php array to 1 dimension

Tags: php, arrays

I have array inside array:

```
{
"0" => array("key" => "code", "id" => "4", "value" => "yes"),
"1" => array("key" => "parameter", "id" => "4", "value" => "0"),
"2" => array("key" => "code", "id" => "5", "value" => "no"),
etc...
}
```

This is what I want to do: I want to have one dimension array in which key would be "id" and value would be "value". However, I need to filter out entries whose key is "parameters". So, in this example, the final array should look like this:

```
{
"4" => "yes",
"5" => "no"
}
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to do this. Could you please help me a bit? I tried writing this foreach inside foreach but I just can't wrap my head around how to filter data.

```
foreach ($settings AS $key => $value) {
            $id = null;
            $value = null;

            foreach ($value AS $key2 => $value2) {
                // No idea how to filter out uneccesary entries and save the correct ones
            }

            $finalArray[$id] = $value;
        }
```

Comment: Use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove entries where `key` is `parameter`; then [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) on the result of that: `$finalArray = array_column(array_filter($settings, function($value) { return $value['key'] !== 'parameter'; }), 'id', 'value');`

Comment: @Marius try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45921364/4369087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it :

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($settings as $setting) {
    if ($setting['key'] != 'parameter') {
        $finalArray[$setting['id']] = $setting['value'];
    }
}
```

Assuming all your entries have keys 'key', 'id' and 'value'.

Comment: The problem is that there can be more keys, not only "code" and "parameter".

Comment: That's not what the question says. If there was other keys important here, the OP would have mentioned them.

Answer (score 2):

use `array_column` and `array_filter` like this, if you want to filter more keys add them to `out_keys` array :

```
<?php

$array = [
   ["key" => "code", "id" => "4", "value" => "yes"],
   ["key" => "parameter", "id" => "4", "value" => "0"],
   ["key" => "code", "id" => "5", "value" => "no"]
];

$out_keys = ['parameter'];

$result = array_column(array_filter($array, function($item) use($out_keys) {
   return !in_array($item['key'], $out_keys);
}), 'value', 'id');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [4] => yes
    [5] => no
)
```

Comment: Can probably reduce the condition used in the callback for `array_filter()` to `'parameter' !== $item['key']`, but otherwise, this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$data` is your starting array, the code below will output what you want in `$result`

```
$result = [];
foreach(array_filter($data, function($el){return $el['key']!='parameter';}) as $el){
  $result[$el['id']] = $el['value'];
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/gRpAs)